# How to compare formated strings in php

Tags: php, string, compare

i have two strings to compare in PHP.
They have same caracters (Uppercase letters separeted by -)  but not in the same sort.
My problem is that i need to know $a to do my query and i only have $b who is generated by the user.

```
$a = 'LC-A-T-P-DPE-ELE';     //saved in bdd
$b = 'T-P-DPE-ELE-LC-A';  //generated by the user

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE col=$a";
```

Comment: `They have same caracters` Well `$a` doesn't have `ER`

Comment: You need to redesign either the table schema or the UI or you're in for a world of hurt (meaning you'd have to search for all permutations).

Comment: Thks Shankar i corrected my example

Comment: Is there any rules to transform/sort elements in $b to $a?
Otherwise you have to try all combination

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode both strings (using '-' as seperator), sort the resulting arrays and then implode back to string.
Something similar to this

```
$arrayA = explode('-', $a);
$arrayB = explode('-', $b);
sort($arrayA);
sort($arrayB);
$aSorted = implode('-', $arrayA);
$bSorted = implode('-', $arrayB);
```

After that $aSorted and $bSorted should be the same string, if $a and $b are equivalent as per your definition.

Comment: Thanks for your time, the problem is that i don t know $a (stored in bdd)